# How does the relationship between 2 tables in Rails models?

Tags: database-design, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables in Rails:

```
CURRENCIES:  
-------------  
| id | name |  
-------------  
|  1 | USD  |  
|  2 | EUR  |   
-------------
```

```
ITEMS:  
----------------------------------------  
| id | name      | price | currency_id | 
----------------------------------------  
|  1 | product a |   100 |           1 |
|  2 | product b |    20 |           2 |
|  3 | product c |    60 |           2 |
|  4 | product d |  NULL |        NULL |
----------------------------------------
```

`ITEMS.price` and `ITEMS.currency_id` are allow `NULL`, but `ITEMS.currency_id` must be set when `ITEMS.price != NULL`.
How does the relationship between those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do the one-to-one relationship in RoR:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :currency
end
```

Depending on your DBMS, you could add a check constraint so that `price` and `currency_id` must be either both null or both with a value.

It also seems to me you could put that in another table

```
PRICES
---------------------------
| id | value | currency_id |  
---------------------------
|  1 | 100   |           1 | 
|  2 | 200   |           2 | 
---------------------------
```

Comment: One of the advantages of the PRICES solution is that you can keep several prices with different currency_id. I'm not sure it's a good think to keep different calculations instead of calculating when needed, though.